# Python regular expression, matching the last word

Tags: python, regex, list

I've the following problem. I'm looking to find all words in a string that typically looks like so
`HelloWorldToYou`
Notice, each word is capitalized as a start followed by the next word and so on.
I'm looking to create a list of words from it. So the final expected output is a list that looks like

```
['Hello','World','To','You']
```

In Python, I used the following

```
mystr = 'HelloWorldToYou'
pat = re.compile(r'([A-Z](.*?))(?=[A-Z]+)')
[x[0] for x in pat.findall(mystr)]
['Hello', 'World', 'To']
```

However, I'm unable to capture the last word 'You'. Is there a way to get at this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at @stribzhev's example. The issue you're having is because your script is looking for an instance where you do not have a capital letter after "You".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the alternation with `$`:

```
import re
mystr = 'HelloWorldToYou'
pat = re.compile(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)')
# or your version with `.*?`: pat = re.compile(r'([A-Z].*?)(?=[A-Z]+|$)')
print pat.findall(mystr)
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Qf5mpx)

Output:

```
['Hello', 'World', 'To', 'You']
```

**Regex explanation**:

- `([A-Z][a-z]*)` - A capturing group that matches

  - `[A-Z]` a capital English letter followed by
  - `[a-z]*` - optional number of lowercase English letters

     -OR-
  - `.*?` - Match any characters other than a newline lazily

The lookahead can be omitted if we use `[a-z]*`, but if you use `.*?`, then use it:

- `(?=[A-Z]+|$)` - Up to an uppercase English letter (we can actually remove `+` here), **OR** the end of string (`$`).

If you do not use a look-ahead version, you can even remove the capturing group for better performance and [use `finditer`](https://ideone.com/FIzLOO):

```
import re
mystr = 'HelloWorldToYou'
pat = re.compile(r'[A-Z][a-z]*')
print [x.group() for x in pat.finditer(mystr)]
```